# Using JavaScript/jQuery to move input field position in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have the following form on my website

```
input a
input b
input c
```

Is it possible to have the following done using jQuery?

```
input a
input c
input b
```

Keep in mind that the form still needs to collect the data correctly.

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, it's easier, albeit the same technique, with `id`s but if you just know which one you want to move, then:

```
$('input:text:nth-child(3)').insertAfter($('input:text:nth-child(1)'));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p43y6/)

[JS Fiddle of `id`-based approach (generously offered by Vega)](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/MQqHF/).

Or, similarly:

```
$('input:text:nth-child(3)').appendTo($('input:text:nth-child(1)').parent());
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p43y6/1/).

[JS Fiddle demo of `id`-based approach](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MQqHF/2/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
- [`:nth-child()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).
- [`:text` selector](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/).

Comment: Wow dude, thank you; worked like a charm! I have been Googling this but couldn't find something that worked. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Vega, thank you kindly! Edited in, and used as the basis for the second `id`-based demo. =)